# Can't use libopenh264-2.0.0-android.so for my android app because of 32-bit support

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, openh264

In my video editing android app, because of licensing reason, I had to download libopenh264-2.0.0-android.so.bz2 dynamically from this site https://github.com/cisco/openh264/releases to use with ffmpeg.

However, if I disable 64-bit for the app, I can't publish the app on Google Play. The store requires 64-bit support.
If I enable 64-bit, I can't use the openh264-android.so library, the ffmpeg commands don't work

Here is the way I disabled 64-bit in build.gradle

```html
ndk {
abiFilters "armeabi","armeabi-v7a","x86"
}
```

Anyone can help on this issue please? thanks

Comment: Why can you use androids `MediaCodec` api?

Comment: What are the licensing reasons not to build arm64 from sources?

Comment: The Cisco-provided binary is separately downloaded to an end user’s device, and not integrated into or combined with third party software prior to being downloaded to the end user’s device; http://www.openh264.org/BINARY_LICENSE.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cisco provided openh264.so for android 64bit
https://github.com/cisco/openh264/releases/tag/v2.0.0